# ActiveRecord attempting to connect to the wrong database using rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, passenger, rbenv

Getting an error in `/log/production.log` when performing get request on site root:

```
I, [2016-03-21T02:21:38.485274 #12750]  INFO -- :
    Started GET "/" for 174.xx.xxx.xxx at 2016-03-21 02:21:38 -0600
F, [2016-03-21T02:21:38.493250 #12750] FATAL -- :
    ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "y" does not exist)
```

It says `database "y" does not exist`. First off, `y` is not a database, so I know it doesn't exist.

Secondly, `database.yml` specifies `ydb` as the database that the app should connect to - not `y`.

**config/database.yml:**

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  host: <%= ENV['Y_PG_HOST'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['Y_PG_DB'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['Y_PG_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['Y_PG_PASS'] %>
```

Using rbenv to declare the env vars:

**.rbenv-vars**

```
  Y_PG_HOST=localhost
  Y_PG_DB=ydb
  Y_PG_USER=y
  Y_PG_PASS=*********
```

Update

Thanks to @Meshpi, it appears that `rbenv` is where the issue is occurring. When the env vars are placed directly in `database.yml`, the server loads the site as expected.

What is puzzling is that from `echo $Y_PG_DB`, the shell returns `ydb`, not `y`.

Comment: How are you running the server? Does it work if you export the vars first with `export $(cat .rbenv-vars | xargs)`?

Comment: k, tried that and it didn't change the error message. Also, I am using Passenger + Nginx. Furthermore, I haven't done anything to the `postgresql.conf` or `pg_hba.conf` files - I left them untouched as installed.

Comment: Have you tried ruling out rbenv as the culprit by setting the values directly in your database.yml instead of environment variables?

Comment: @Meshpi Well I'll be derned. You're right, the issue seems to lie with `rbenv`. I put the envars directly in `database.yml` and now it's working as expected

Comment: @singularity at least we know where to look. I wonder why it's reading the rbenv username variable's value as the database name.

Comment: @singularity I'm confident it's because .rbenv won't kick in when the `database.yml` file is read. That doesn't mean you can't use ENV variables, it's just you need to do what I suggest above before restarting the server.

Comment: @toomanyredirects Here's what I did, but still getting the same error: 1. `export $(cat .rbenv-vars | xargs)` 2. `sudo killall nginx` 3. `sudo /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx` 4. `touch tmp/restart.txt` - still getting the same error. You might be right, but there could be something else in my environment that is misconfigured.

Comment: If you're starting nginx as root you also need to export the vars as root: `sudo export $(cat .rbenv-vars | xargs)`

Comment: I'm not sure how environment vars work in rbenv but is he are they ruby version specific? i.e does the production global Ruby version match the version you're exporting those vars to?

Comment: @toomanyredirects There must be something more basic that's wrong with how I have my linux user setup, because when I run `sudo export $(cat .rbenv-vars | xargs)`, I get an error: `sudo: export: command not found`

Comment: @Meshpi Rbenv documentation says it can set project-specific env vars or global ones. I installed and set a different global ruby version to test and doing `echo $Y_PG_DB` returned `ydb` - regardless of which directory // rbenv ruby version was set.

Comment: @singularity I saw that running `spring stop` will allow spring to read the environment variables when it starts again - https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19256#issuecomment-102980786

Comment: @Meshpi Interesting find. The server I am running doesn't have spring on it. This lead me to test `bundle exec rails console production` > `ENV['Y_PG_DB']` which returned `ydb`. So the production console is getting access to the right variable though when trying to access the website through a web browser the same error is returning.

Comment: What's incredibly baffling to me is that your environment is reading something. It just happens to reading the incorrect value ~ it's swapping username 'y' in place for the database 'ydb'. I'm fresh out of ideas :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Development worked fine. Even `rails console production` on the server worked with `app.get '/'` with no database errors. However, when putting the request through the browser, all hell broke loose.

The problem is that the instructions that Phusion Passenger gives at the end of its installation are not exactly compatible with rbenv-vars.

At the end of the Passenger installation, you are instructed to add the following to `nginx.conf`:

```
passenger_root /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.26;
passenger_ruby /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/ruby;
```

However, then as @mislav [pointed out](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-vars/issues/27), the Ruby scripts would be spinning up the ruby processes directly instead of through rbenv.

To fix this, what needs to be in `nginx.conf` instead is:

```
passenger_root /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.26;
passenger_ruby /home/user/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
```

Hope this helps spare another unsuspecting soul :D