# Rails staging server using old databse connection info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, capistrano, passenger

I was using localhost postgres db for rails server, recently updated my databse.yaml file to point towards rds,  but i found that my server is still saving data to old databse ie.localhost instead of rds.

All change i made is available in `Rails.configuration.database_configuration` but when i check `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.conninfo_hash` it's showing my old databse instead of new db.

I tried to set db name as nil, but still this change was not shown in `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.conninfo_hash`, so it seems like none of my new changes in databse.yaml is used by my server

locally when i try to run the app in staging env it is correctly using new db info, but its not using new db info in my remote staging server.

i tried to restarting the rails server using `cap staging deploy:restart`,reboot my aws ec2 instance but still no luck

app is deployed to remote server using capistrano

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password:
# socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: JandR_development


production:
  <<: *default
  database: qwerty
  username: asdfg
  password: zxcv

staging:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  database: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:staging_db, :database) %>
  username: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:staging_db, :username) %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:staging_db, :password) %>
  host: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:staging_db, :host) %>
  port: 5432




old db config
    staging:
  <<: *default
  database: dbname same as new db name
  username: username same as new username
  password: password same as new password
```

my capistrano staging confile file have only the following line active

```
server 'my_server_ip', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{app db web}
```

Comment: What's your old database config? What's your staging capistrano config?

Comment: @eux i have added old db config, cap staging details

Comment: Just make sure: Did you `set :rails_env, 'staging''` in capistrano config file? Did you check `Rails.env` on staging server console?

Comment: i checked my env in  server using sudo passenger-status and it seems to be showing that i am in production env. But still server is using db details from my staging key mentioned in databse.yaml file

Comment: Weird. It works locally, so it should be something wrong on remote server. You could try 
to deploy to a new server if there's no other way.

Comment: @eux thanks i just found that it was because,env variables were loaded from .rbenv-variables https://stackoverflow.com/q/36126293/5706413

Answer (score 0):

Initially i had set `DATABSE_URL` in `.rbenv-vars` file in root of my project in server. i located this env variable using `grep -inr "DATABASE_URL"` in `home/username` or `~/` folder. Updating the `DATABSE_URL` in .rbenv-vars fixed the issue for me. Actually i forgot about this setup i had done in my server
References: locating env file location https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/823/241745